# Minimum number of arguments for a recursive function to explore matrix

Tags: c, recursion, matrix, arguments

sorry if someone already asked this, didn't find it.

I'm wandering what's the minimum number of arguments i have to pass to a recursive function in order to explore all its values.

I'll make an example; suppose I want to write a function which returns me the sum of all the values contained in a MXM matrix, i can surely do it (and did it) like this:

```
int sum(int mat[][M], int i, int j){
if(j==M-1&&i==M-1){
    return mat[i][j];
}
if(j==M){
    i++;
    j=0;
}
return mat[i][j] + sum(mat, i, j+1);
}
```

Calling

```
sum(mat,0,0);
```

I obtain the result.

My question is: can I obtain the same result writing a function with less arguments?
About the example: can I obtain the same result writing a funtion like:

```
int sum(int mat[][M], int i){...}
```

or just

```
int sum(int mat[][M]){...}
```

?

More abstractly speaking, what is the minimum number of arguments I need to pass to a recursive function in order to explore a matrix?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You need at least one argument that will change in the recursive call, otherwise you'll have an infinite loop.

Comment: So it's not possible to get the sum passing only the matrix as an argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with one argument by having it be the row-major index of the element to add. The function can calculate the row and column indexes from that.

```
int sum(int mat[M][M], int x){
    int i = x / M;
    int j = x % M;
    if(j==M-1 && i==M-1){
        return mat[i][j];
    }
    return mat[i][j] + sum(mat, x+1);
}
```

You can't do it by just passing the array, because you need some way of telling when you've reached the base case so the recursion should stop. A recursive call has to have some parameter that changes each time, getting closer to the base case. But the array value doesn't change.

Comment: Thank you. Curiosity: why did you specify M inside both square brackets in mat[M][M]? Is there a reason or is it just your way of writing?